# How to run/test JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, tools

I'm reading David Flanagan's "[JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th ed](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)".

It only actually tells users how to run JS code on page 311, where users are told of the following solutions:

"Client-side JavaScript code is embedded within HTML documents in four ways:

- Inline, between a pair of `<script>` and `</script>` tags
- From an external file specified by the `src` attribute in a `<script>` tag
- In an HTML event handler attribute, such as `onclick` or `onmouseover`
- In a URL that uses the special javascript: protocol."

I was wondering what professional JS developers use to write and test their code: Do they use a good text editor with syntax high-lighting + autocompletion, hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser to reload the page every time they make a change, and use some add-on in the browser to investigate errors? Or are there full-fledged IDE's similar to MS VisualStudio for non-web languages?

Comment: I have the 5th ed of that book and the first how-to on running JS code with a fully working example of client-side JavaScript is on page 4?

Comment: I don't think this is off topic. Yes, developers use good editors with syntax highlighting. Yes, we refresh a page when we need to test new/updated code. There is also the javascript console (e.g. press shift-ctrl-i in Chrome) which allows adding javascript to a page in real time.